# Screen artifacts after waking laptop from sleep

Tags: display, amd-graphics

I used the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU#Screen_artifacts_and_frequency_problem)  to solve this problem but the issue still persists. I am using only `amdgpu` currently .

```
inxi -b
System:    Host: Asus Kernel: 5.4.124-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.21.5 Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X570ZD_F570ZD v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X570ZD v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: X570ZD.312 
           date: 02/25/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 23.1 Wh (55.1%) condition: 41.9/48.1 Wh (87.1%) volts: 11.7 min: 11.7 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx [MT MCP] speed: 1889 MHz min/max: 1600/2000 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Device-2: AMD Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
           Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: amdgpu,ati,nouveau unloaded: modesetting 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics (RAVEN DRM 3.35.0 5.4.124-1-MANJARO LLVM 12.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.1.2 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           Device-3: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 117.66 GiB (12.6%) 
Info:      Processes: 233 Uptime: 11m Memory: 6.74 GiB used: 2.36 GiB (35.1%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.04
```

Answer (score 0):

`5.4.124` - this kernel is ancient. Try 5.12.13.